# Chrome automatically stopping while using Selenium

Tags: python, class, google-chrome, selenium-webdriver, automation

I am using class-based approach for an automation task via selenium. Chrome is automatically stopping after loading the page. That's why "add_experimental_option("detach", True)" is added. But i can't make it work in the following code. This is my booking.py code.

```
import booking.constant as const
from selenium import webdriver
import os


options = webdriver.ChromeOptions()
options.add_experimental_option("detach", True)
driver = webdriver.Chrome(options=options)


class booking(driver):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r'C:\SeleniumDrivers'):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super(booking, self).__init__()

    def land_first_page(self):
        self.get(const.base_url)
```

This method works, but Chrome is automatically closed opening the web page.

```
class booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r'C:\SeleniumDrivers'):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super(booking, self).__init__()
```

the main py file

```
from booking.booking import booking

inst = booking()
inst.land_first_page()
```

```
ERROR:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\KSN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\run.py", line 1, in <module>
  from booking.booking import booking
File "C:\Users\KSN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\booking\booking.py", line 11, in <module>
    class booking(driver):
  File "C:\Users\KSN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chrome\webdriver.py", line 80, in __init__
    super().__init__(
  File "C:\Users\KSN\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\venv\Lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\chromium\webdriver.py", line 94, in __init__
    if options._ignore_local_proxy:
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute '_ignore_local_proxy'
```

Comment: problem is in the booking.py file. post it. and post a text based error as well. images are no good

Comment: @RolandasUlevicius this is my booking.py code. I have edited the question please check it again, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This latter method of yours seems to work fine

```
class booking(webdriver.Chrome):
    def __init__(self, driver_path=r'C:\SeleniumDrivers'):
        self.driver_path = driver_path
        os.environ['PATH'] += self.driver_path
        super(booking, self).__init__()

    def land_first_page(self):
        self.get(const.base_url)
```

I only received error when I pass a url to the `.get(url)` method that does not begin with **https://** or **http://**. So check and make sure your `const.base_url` is correct

If not the case and to my understanding, selenium is loading your page and when done, if no other code to execute afterwards then the main program terminates and all other processes also are terminated including the selenium session thus the browser closes

Well, so if you want to keep the browser open, you could freeze the main thread from terminating by calling the `input()` function after calling the `.land_first_page()` method

```
inst = booking()
inst.land_first_page()
input("press any key to continue...")
```